# Pyinstaller installation in DebIan Linux

Tags: python, linux

I am on Debian Linux and I am trying to install Pyinstaller, for making a standalone exe file from python script, into my debian linux. I downloaded from this [link](http://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller.git) to get Pyinstaller. But can't find proper installation instruction and found one discussion [here](http://excid3.com/blog/pyinstaller-a-simple-tutorial/). 
What I did was

(1) go to the pyinstaller folder and 
    sudo python setup.py
    The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 14, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

(2) I don't have source/linux folder in my Pyinstaller folder according to the discussion in the second link.
Where can I find proper instruction for the installation. Even in this [manual](http://www.pyinstaller.org/static/docs/Manual_v1.1.html), it is not clear how to install for Linux.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to install python-setuptools

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

Installation pyinstaller:
You can pip install the pyinstaller

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

if you do not have pip then you can install pip using

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Comment: yeah now I can run python setup.py install. Then I go into the next step as python ../pyinstaller.py --onefile /home/pi/PY_programs/camera_record.py. But I am end up as IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pi/PyInstaller-2.1/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/bootloader/Linux-32bit-arm/run'. I have only Linux-32bit.I don't have Linux-32bit-arm.

Comment: I also run python configure.py. But nothing happened.

Comment: I am not sure but I think it's not an issue.

Comment: yeah now I can make a file with no extension. but the file is empty. I am still checking.

Comment: @batuman if my answer helped you in you original query, please consider accepting it as the correct answer, thanks...

Comment: hi Jord. I am still struggling. I am new to Python. I think something is wrong. All discussions found for pyinstaller installation, they use the Capital letter to run the script for example python Configure.py. If I run the script with such capital letter, I got error as file not found. I have to use smaller letter as python configure.py. What is wrong? Your answer helped me. But I am still struggling to make exe using Pyinstaller.

Comment: @batuman i have added steps to pip install pyinstaller, if it still doesnt work and you have to install it from source then i will have to  download the source and install it :D

Comment: Thanks Jord. Will try today.

Comment: Hi Jord, it is still the same. After installing pip install pyinstaller. I have Python2.6, 2.7 and 3.2 at usr/local/lib. Then I go to 2.7/dist-package/egg/Pyinstaller. Then I tried python2.7 configure.py, and python2.7 makespec.py --onefile camera_record.py. Nothing happened.

Comment: @batuman well we have come this far.. originally installing pyinstaller was a pain.. 
pip install was successful means you have pyinstaller on your system now..

Comment: Yeah Jord, thanks. My intention is I am going to run my python exe for camera capture program using remote ssh from my hand phone. Let me try some more. Thanks

Comment: Actually I can make spec file using the command python pyinstaller.py --onefile script.py. During that run the error is can't find Linux-32bit-arm/run. I am running pyinstaller on Raspberry Pi linux, it has arm processor. I think that is the problem, so when I run python build.py script.spec. I got exe file but nothing inside.

Comment: Actually I need to build of my own for my platform according to this http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#building-the-bootloader

Comment: Ha ha, finally i got exe file. I need bootloader for Linux-32bit-arm as my debian is in Rapberry PI. I followed the steps http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#building-the-bootloader at building. Then using python, I can make exe file. thanks